# Cannot read property in express

Tags: node.js, express, post, undefined, body-parser

Sorry, know that such questions are popular, but i couldn't find answer there.

Have output

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

that links to post request in this file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let query = 'select event.id,   event.title,    event.description,  event.date, place.title as place,   organisator.title as organisator,   subcategory.title as subcategory from ((event inner join place on event.place_id = place.id) inner join organisator on event.organisator_id = organisator.id) inner join subcategory on event.subcategory_id = subcategory.id';
    res.locals.connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.render('index', { title: 'Events', data: results });
    });
});

router.post('/add', function (err, req, res) {
    const query = "insert into event (title, description, event.date, subcategory_id, place_id, organisator_id) values ('" + req.body.title + "','" + req.body.description + "','" + req.body.date + "',(SELECT id from subcategory WHERE title = '" + req.body.subcategory + "'),(SELECT id from place WHERE title = '" + req.body.place + "'),(SELECT id from organisator WHERE title = '" + req.body.organisator + "'))";
    connection.query(query, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for scrolling, just have such queries.
Found some answers that body-parser should be used before anything, but i think i don't have such problem. There is my app file.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mysql = require("mysql");
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'Strange3865hum31315',
        database : 'minskevents'
    });
    res.locals.connection.connect();
    next();
});

app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/events', require('./routes/events'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4000);
if(server.listening){
  console.log('Server is listening on port 4000');
}

module.exports = app;
```

I get data from html form

```
<form action="/events/add" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Event name" />
        <input type="text" name="subcategory" placeholder="Category" />
        <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
        <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="Place" />
        <input type="text" name="organisator" placeholder="Organisator" />
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" onkeyup="adjust_textarea(this)"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </form>
```

Comment: In your `POST` request function, remove `err` as the first argument. Instead, have `(req, res, next)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handlers in express have to have [4 arguments, not 3](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Therefore your `/add` route of this:

`router.post('/add', function (err, req, res) {`

Is actually a normal route where the first parameter is getting filled with the `req` (request), the second with the `res` (response), the third with the `next`function. Because you named the second parameter `req` you've created a confusing scenario where `req` is the response, `err` is the request, and `res` is the next function.

Because the response doesn't have a `body` property and you've named the response `req`, your `req.body.title` is trying to property into an undefined value (`body`). Rename your parameters `req, res, next` and I think you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the get method you are referencing the title as `event.title` but in the post just as `title` . why?

Comment: If you're only posting a question, without answering, that would probably be better served being a comment to the question than down here in answers. Also, the answer is that is embedded SQL in that string, so `event` in that case is a table.

Comment: [I agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913896/232629), but this still is a question, and not an answer. Therefore it shouldn't be an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: Well that's ridiculous. I didn't know that. Fair enough.